# How can I view assembly code produced for C functions?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-flags

I need to view the assembly code produced for certain C functions.

What flags should I use when compiling the C code using the `g++` compiler?

Comment: It depends on which compiler you use.

Comment: g++ is not a C compiler.

Comment: on a linux system i compile my programs using g++ main.c etc... so dont use g++?

Comment: @Need4Sleep: `main.cpp` looks like C++ source code. So, C or C++? They are not the same language (although the answer shall be the same for both g++ and gcc).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may add the `-S` tag to see the assembly code.

Like for a file `TEST.c`, with `gcc`, do,

```
gcc TEST.c -S
```

`clang` also outputs the assembly code with a similar `-S` tag.

After that just look for a file with a `.S` extension.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the command **objdump** in a binary you have to see the assembler code, in linux

Answer (score 3):

With `gcc` or `g++` compiler, you can use the `-S` flag to see the assembly code generated.

> #### GNU C Compiler Documentation
>
> `-S`: Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.
>
> By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix `.c`, `.i`, etc., with `.s`.
>
> Input files that don't require compilation are ignored.

Then you have to look for the identifier of your function in the file (if the compiler has not inlined it).