# How can I convert this C code into Assembly IA32?

Tags: c, assembly, converters

I would like to know if there is a quick way to convert this code into Assembly from IA32 please!

```
void function1(char trs[], int let[26]) {
    int i;
    int ind;

    int x = trs[i];

    for(i=0; trs[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if (x>='a' && x<='z')
            ind = x - 'a';  
            let[ind]++;

        if (x>='A' && x<='Z')
            ind=x - 'A';

        let[ind]++;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a C compiler! It's what they do!

Comment: It is certainly possible, but I doubt it will be quick unless you know IA32 assembly very well. Also, I doubt many people will be able to hand-optimize it better than a compiler would, if that's what you want. If it's for school-work then you should do it yourself, and come back here with your attempt if you have problems with it.

Comment: Also note you are missing some curly braces. This is not python where indentation matters;)

Comment: gcc -S

Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241771/how-can-i-view-assembly-code-produced-for-c-functions

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354899/how-can-i-see-the-assembly-code-that-is-generated-by-a-gcc-any-flavor-compiler

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. You're assigning `x` to `trs[i]` outside of the loop, before `i` is even assigned a value. `x` is never modified in the loop, so whatever you do in that loop will be done to the same array element at each iteration. No idea what you think your code is going to do, but it's almost certain that what you've written won't do what you expect.

Comment: okay thank you! I'm new at this C/Assembly thing so sorry for all the mistakes ahah

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `gcc`, you can just use `gcc -S main.c -o main.s`.

This outputs assembly code (GAS flavour) far faster than any human can :)

But seriously, if you wanted to convert this by hand, I would recommend converting your code into plain English, and then into Assembly.